# How do I get a bool from a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

To do cross-thread operations, I use the following:
`this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => myMethod());`

However, I can't do, for example, the following:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => bool myBool = getBool()); 
return myBool;
```

How would I do this? I can't just do bool myBool = getBool();
because I get a cross-threading operation error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using task-based asynchrony rather than managing your own threads. With task-based asynchrony you simply `await` the value of the task; a `Task<bool>` will then hand you back the bool value and resume execution on a thread appropriate to the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
delegate T MyDelegate<out T>();
public bool MethodName()
{
    bool b = (bool)this.Invoke(new MyDelegate<bool>(() => getBool()));
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Would I call this just by the method name?

Comment: @Adam: What do you mean exactly? Now you can just call `MethodName()` to get the bool, but you can replace `MethodName` with the name that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean

But you could do something like this

```
bool myBool = false;
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => myBool = getBool()));
return myBool;
```

If am wrong pls make me clear

Comment: Actually, the thing is, I want to use it in an if-statement: `if (this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => !myBool))) {` ... But that doesn't work